# Use of disable fork inside forever loop of fork-join

Tags: system-verilog

I am having "disable fork" inside a fork-join which embeds inside forever begin.
So I am expecting every time new process would be created & killed once either of the thread gets finished. But it runs only once .

I am having the below code which is executing only once.

```
module tb();
  
  `timescale 1ns/1ns
  
  bit clk;
  
  always #2 clk =~ clk;
  
  task automatic req_ack(ref bit req, ref bit ack, input string name);
    forever begin
          $display("waiting for req");
          @(req);
          $display("Req changed at %t for %0d", $time, req);
          fork
            begin
              #5us;
              $display("ACK expired");
              disable fork;
            end
            begin
              wait(ack == req); //This will succeed
              $display("Ack received for %s at %t", name, $time);                    
              disable fork;
            end
          join
    end
  endtask
        
  bit tx_req, tx_ack;
        
  initial begin
    repeat(5) @(posedge clk);
    tx_req = 1;
    repeat(5) @(posedge clk);
    tx_ack = 1;
    $display("ack from tb at %t", $time);
    repeat(5) @(posedge clk);
    tx_req = 0;
    repeat(5) @(posedge clk);
    tx_ack = 0;    
    repeat(15) @(posedge clk);
    $finish;
  end
        
  initial begin
    req_ack(tx_req, tx_ack, "TX");
  end
  
  
endmodule
```

In the above task, once ack_arrival gets finished, " disable fork" kills the whole task instead of the process such that task doesn't detect any other "req" change.
Can someone please explain why does it so ?

Comment: I simulated the above here :  https://www.edaplayground.com/x/VQBP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`disable fork` disables the *children* of the current thread. Your statement is inside the forked process which has no children. So the `join` cannot happen until your expiration timeout occurs at **5µs**. But, you call `$finish` at 138ns before that ever has a chance of happening. If you change your expiration delay to **5ns**, you will see what is happening.

You should use `fork/join_any` with a `disable fork` immediately afterwards.

```
// `timescale needs to go outside module

 `timescale 1ns/1ns


module tb();
  
  
  bit clk;
  
  always #2 clk =~ clk;
  
  task automatic req_ack(ref bit req, ref bit ack, input string name);
    bit local_req, local_ack; 
    fork
      // workaround for accessing ref arguments in fork/join_any
      forever @req local_req = req;
      forever @ack local_ack = ack;
      forever begin
        $display("waiting for req");
        @(req);
        $display("Req changed at %t for %0d", $time, req);
        fork
          begin
            #5us;
            $display("ACK expired");
          end
          begin
            wait(local_ack == local_req); //This will succeed
           $display("Ack received for %s at %t", name, $time);                    
          end
        join_any
        disable fork;
      end
    join
  endtask
        
  bit tx_req, tx_ack;
        
  initial begin
    repeat(5) @(posedge clk);
    tx_req <= 1; // use NBA to avoid tb races
    repeat(5) @(posedge clk);
    tx_ack <= 1;
    $display("ack from tb at %t", $time);
    repeat(5) @(posedge clk);
    tx_req <= 0;
    repeat(5) @(posedge clk);
    tx_ack <= 0;    
    repeat(15) @(posedge clk);
    $finish;
  end
        
  initial begin
    req_ack(tx_req, tx_ack, "TX");
  end
  
  
endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks dave. As you mentioned, disable fork kills only the child process which is null in this case. So why does forever loop terminates ?

Comment: @GayathriHariharakrishnan. There will be one child process terminated by the `disable fork` The `fork/join_any` creates two child processes(the two begin/end blocks), but one of them will have completed for the `join_any` to proceed.

Answer (score -2):

A flawed solution

```
program automatic test;
    bit tx_req = 0;
    
    task automatic req_ack(ref bit req);
       while(1) begin
            @(req);
            fork: STOP_THIS
                begin : timeout
                    int delay = $urandom_range(1,3);
                    repeat(delay) #1;
                    $display("timeout thread run");
                    disable STOP_THIS;
                end
                begin : ack_arrival
                    int delay = $urandom_range(1,3);
                    repeat(delay) #1;
                    $display("ack_arrival thread run"); 
                    disable STOP_THIS;
                end 
            join
        end
    endtask : req_ack
 
    initial begin     
        req_ack(tx_req); 
    end
    initial begin
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) begin
            tx_req = i%2;
            #10;
        end
    end            
endprogram
```

Here is the link of testbench [EDA playgroup](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/Jerh)

Comment: Although this code works as a possible solution, disabling a statement label does not always work if task is reentrant. It disables all invocations of the task. Also the reason why the original code does not work is incorrect.

Comment: @dave_59 Thanks dave, my understanding is wrong. I have removed the incorrect part of the answer